# Apache with Eruby not parsing require statement properly

Tags: ruby, apache2, require, eruby

I recently configured Apache with eruby and got some rhtml pages running. I have a `globalfunctions.rb` file that I want to be available to all of the pages that I have running on the site.

However, I have a problem: putting a require statement in rhtml makes it break and return error 500. Here's the code for the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home | Quantum Software</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<%
require './globalfunctions.rb'
%>
<div class="contentBox">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the global functions file:

```
def get_file_name()
    return File.basename(__FILE__)
end

def new_nav_link( target, title )
    currentFileName = get_file_name()

    if target == currentFileName
        puts %Q@<a href="#{target}" class="selected">#{title}</a>@
    else
        puts %Q@<a href="#{target}">#{title}</a>@
    end
end
```

And lastly, here's the last few lines of error.log:

```
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] :
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] no such file to load -- ./globalfunctions.rb
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103]  (
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] LoadError
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] )
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] --- generated code ---
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "<html>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "<head>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "\\t<title>Home | Quantum Software</title>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "\\t<link rel=\\"stylesheet\\" type=\\"text/css\\" href=\\"style.css\\" />\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "</head>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "<body>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103]
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] require "./globalfunctions.rb"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "<div class=\\"contentBox\\">\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "</div>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "</body>\\n"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] print "</html>"
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] ----------------------
[Fri Apr 27 23:22:59 2012] [error] [client 174.252.185.103] Premature end of script headers: eruby
[Fri Apr 27 23:23:24 2012] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
[Fri Apr 27 23:23:24 2012] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
[Fri Apr 27 23:24:04 2012] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
[Fri Apr 27 23:27:03 2012] [error] an unknown filter was not added: includes
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out `$LOAD_PATH` and `Dir.pwd` inside your rhtml file:

```
<!-- For example like this -->
<p>
  The load path is: <br />
  <%= $LOAD_PATH.join("<br />\n") %>
</p>
<p> 
  The current working directory is: <%= Dir.pwd %>
</p>
```

You will probably find that the current working directory (`Dir.pwd`) of the Ruby interpreter is not the same as the location of your rhtml file. So Ruby cannot find `globalfunctions` because it only looks for it in `$LOAD_PATH`.

In that case you need to require your file with an absolute path, like:

```
require '/var/www/mypages/globalfuntions'
```

OR alternatively place your `globalfuntions.rb` either in any directory that `$LOAD_PATH` points to, or into the place that `Dir.pwd` points to (the current working directory of the Ruby interpreter).